# Trying to find top watched genres per gender based on dataframe with two columns genre and gender

Tags: python

I'm currently working with a large movie dataset, which I have filtered to 2 columns: `Genre` and `Gender`.

To visualize this:

```
Genre:        Gender:
Romance       Male
Tech          Male
Romance       Male
Comedy        Female
Tech          Female
Comedy        Male
Romance       Female
Romance       Male
```

I want to show the top 3 most viewed genres per gender, but I can't seem to get the right code.

What I've tried:

```
df_final_gender['name'].groupby(df_final_gender['GENDER']).describe()
```

Which shows only the most viewed (top) genre of each gender. I want the top 3 of each gender, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Genre': ['Romance', 'Tech', 'Romance', 'Comedy', 'Tech', 'Comedy', 'Romance', 'Romance',], 
    'Gender': ['Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male',]})
```

Add an extra column for counts:

```
df['value'] = 1
```

This gives you:

```
    Genre   Gender  value
0   Romance Male    1
1   Tech    Male    1
2   Romance Male    1
3   Comedy  Female  1
4   Tech    Female  1
5   Comedy  Male    1
6   Romance Female  1
7   Romance Male    1
```

Then group by the two fields Genre and Gender and get the counts:

```
counts = df.groupby(['Genre', 'Gender']).count()
```

Outputs:

```
                value
Genre   Gender  
Comedy  Female  1
        Male    1
Romance Female  1
        Male    3
Tech    Female  1
        Male    1
```

You can sort:

```
sorted = counts.sort_values(by='value', ascending=False)
```

And plot:

```
sorted.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15,8))
```

Will get you:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it working :). One question (sorry I'm a newbie) to understand the reasoning; why did you create the 'value' column? Is it so the .count function can count how many 1's there are for that genre and name? Could you explain that? Trying to learn :)

Comment: yes exactly, otherwise the `.count()` wouldn't return any values - they will be all empty.

Answer (score 0):

slice by column and then run this function pd.Series.value_counts()
`df["Gender"].value_counts()`